# jquery script tag visible in each page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have included this code using php "include" at the end of the body tag in

```
</div>
<?php include "jq.php" ?>

</body>
</html>
```

contents of jq.php----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 if (!window.jQuery)
 {
      document.write('<script src="./script/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
  }
</script>
```

-----------------but it is visible at the end of each page---------------------------- [image: footer]

Comment: There's no reason that should display like that. Are you sure that your include in PHP is correct - can you post the code that pulls that page in to the parent page?

Comment: Some browsers won't generate `script` elements in the page. There are ways round this, but that's not your issue. For whatever reason the text content of your script is being encoded into HTML characters - try using `View source` and see if the code is actual HTML or characters like `&lt;` or `&gt;`

Comment: the source is correctly showing script tag

Comment: All I can suggest is adding the `type="text/javascript"` attribute to the `script` element. What browser are you using - do you have anywhere you can link us to see this in the wild?

Comment: can we write this in a javscript file instead of inline.

Answer (score 0):

There's still not much to go on why this isn't working without looking at a lot more of your codebase.

I'd suggest a few things. Firstly, that you probably don't need to include a local copy unless you're doing development work - the chances of Google's CDN being down are very low, and if the user can't access it you'll likely have trouble with other components of the page anyway.

If you *do* need the local version for development (e.g. if you want to test the site when you're offline) then simply add this to PHP:

```
if (is_development()){
    echo '<script src="./script/jquery.min.js"></script>';
}
else {
    echo '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
}
```

Where `is_development()` checks some defined CONSTANT or (less ideally) a global variable or local file.

The final approach would be to simply include the jQuery code at the top of your own JS file:

```
if (!window.jQuery){
    var jQuery=.... // full minified jQuery here
}
```

None of those really answer your query but they should help you continue with your development without too many more problems relating to this issue.